# heroku : how to get the envPort on other js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to make my node application working on heroku, and i stumble upon a, i'm sure common problem, but, i can't sort it out.

my project is a 3 part system, composed of :

- a server file running express and socket.io
- a "web app" in the public folder of the express node server
- a stand alone node app, runned on my comp, linked to an arduino board

on my computer everything runs fine, since everybody listen to the node server from the same ip/port. but in herku since the port is dynamic, i can't get the two other components to know where to connect to.

i define my port like this :

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

and log the port on server up via a console.log statement.

after checking my logs a few time, and then looked at the heroku doc, i realised that i can't have a static port on heroku.

So i'm kind of lost on how can i get the two other component to get heroku port.

side note : here are the solution i will try to implement if i can't get it to work

1. separate the web server and the io server so i can listen to the IO server itself, this solution IS working, but i would prefer having only one heroku instance running for that
2. make the io server listening to the express server event, it should work ... but this is not solving the issue for the part on my computer.
3. jump of a big bridge, resolve no issue, but will make the issues less important.

thanks for the time you spent reading my existentials problems, and thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Is everything supposed to listen to the same port? Then can't they all listen to `process.env.PORT`?

Comment: since on part of the system is not hosted on heroku, this is not a possible solution (this is a system to remote control arduino boards, so the arduinos will NOT be running inside the heroku app :)

Comment: Ah now I understand the problem :) But I'm confused, is it the standalone on your computer that doesn't know the port of your heroku app? Is it not possible to listen to the public domain name (app_name.herokuapp.com)?

Comment: mhhh i should try that, yes ... i belived the port was needed as well. i'll check it tonight, my adruino is not online now

Comment: I thought (but I could be wrong) that it's not even possible to access the port from outside, and it's only used by their internal routing system.

Comment: just tried it on the pure heroku part, ad it works, will check the external part tognight, but it seems that you won an answer, for my problem, i would, still, need to understant how can i pass this value, tho :)

Comment: since i can't reward a comment, please post your comment as an answer if you want to be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect external apps to a heroku app you don't need to know the port. Since the app is accessible through a domain name you may simple connect to that one (eg `app_name.herokuapps.com`, or get your own domain if you prefer).

Comment: i accepted this answer since it is actually true, i do recive messages from the server, but it seems that my board can't emmit to the server without the right port, strangly

Comment: Have you enabled long-/xhr-polling? Just realized heroku doesn't support sockets... See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku